# How to format numeric, such 14.5, to hour, such as 14:30, on r?

Tags: r, time, numeric

I have a numeric column called "hh" with hours in such format:

```
hh
14.5
15.0
15.5
```

... representing a whole day
I want to format as hour such as:

```
14:30
15:00
15:30
```

I tried

```
format(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+df$HH), "%H:%M", tz="UTC", origin="UTC")
```

and did not worked.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for the reference! Wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but it was good. I save it this solution with a star anyway because I'm always facing problems like this. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you ask about how to format the number, here's a solution that outputs the result as a string with your desired formatting.

```
library(stringr)
paste(hh %/% 1, str_pad(60 * (hh - (hh %/% 1)), width = 2, pad = 0), sep = ":")
```

If you want it saved as a POSIX object you should refer to what @loki posted in comments.